# Prove that $(A \cup B)−(A \cap B) = (A− B) \cup (B − A)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Prove that   $$(A \cup B)−(A \cap B) = (A− B) \cup (B − A)$$ by showing that the left hand side is the subset of the right hand side and vice versa.

#### Progress

Let $x$ be an element of LHS. Then x is an element of (A or B) and x is not an element of (A and B). So x is an element of (A or B) & negation of (A and B). Then I used laws to re-arrange it to get the right hand side. And did the same with the RHS.

Comment: Let x be an element of LHS. Then x is an element of (A or B) and x is not an element of (A and B). So x is an element of (A or B) & negation of (A and B). Then I used laws to re-arrange it to get the right hand side. And did the same with the RHS.

Comment: "Then I used laws to re-arrange it to get the right hand side." This sounds like a proof, no?

Comment: In order to show LHS equal RHS, we need to show two ways. First is LHS is subset of RHS. Another way is RHS is subset of LHS. Then, we can conclude LHS and RHS are equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the set on the left hand side. If $x\in (A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)$, then $x\in A\cup B$, but $x\notin A\cap B$. This means that $x$ is an element of either $A$ or $B$, but not both simultaneously.

$x\in A$, then as it is not in both $A$ and $B$ simultaneously, $x\in A\setminus B$. On the other hand, if instead $x\in B$, for similar reasons $x\in B\setminus A$.

Since $x$ must be in one of the sets $A$ or $B$, this implies that $x\in(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$, proving the containment

$$(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)\subset (A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$$

Now consider the set on the right hand side. If $x\in (A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$, so either $x\in A\setminus B$ or $x\in B\setminus A$. In each case, $x\in A\cup B$ (since $x$ is some member of either $A$ or $B$). Also, $x$ cannot be in $A\cap B$ (in the first case, it is in $A$ not $B$, in the second it is in $B$ not $A$), as it cannot be in both sets simultaneously.

This implies that $x\in(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)$,  proving the containment

$$(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)\subset (A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)$$

Therefore the sets are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in A\cup B$.

- if $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$: this is the case $x\in A-B$
- or if $x\in B$ and $x\notin A$: $x\in B-A$
- or $x\in A$ and $x\in B$: $x\in A\cap B$

That is: the sets
$$
A-B, B-A, A\cap B
$$do not cross and their union is $A\cup B$.
Hence,
$$
(A\cup B) - (A\cap B) = (A-B) \cup (B-A)
$$
and the RHS union is disjoint.